# How to access android.R in core libgdx package?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

As per title. I tried passing the R object in the call from AndroidLauncher to the Game class in core. But when I try to import android.R so I can create an object of that type in core class, I get this message from Android Studio:

"Don't include android.R here; use a fully qualified name for each usage instead. Importing android.R is usually not intentional; it sometimes happens when you use an IDE and ask it to automatically add imports at a time when your project's R class it not present.  Once the import is there you might get a lot of "confusing" error messages because of course the fields available on android.R are not the ones you'd expect from just looking at your own R class."

I only need the strings from the ids.xml, so I thought about putting those values into an array before passing, but that seems a little elaborate. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code although you didn't provide enough information, my guess is that this might be useful as well https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Internationalization-and-Localization